# Search inside files with Nemo?

Tags: linux-mint, find, search, nemo, file-search

Is it possible to search the **content** of files in Linux Mint Debian Edition 4? Is this functionality implemented in `Nemo` or can this only be done in the terminal? If so, how?

Problem: I need to find a Python script in which a certain string occurs.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux) cover you?

Comment: As a terminal-based solution, yes - thx. But is it possible to do this from the GUI, i.e. is such functionality implemented? Similar to what Windows Explorer does

Comment: Gnome's File manager have builtin indexer, however it is per-user.

Comment: So you mean that I should install `Gnome`? I think it's also the "stock" file manager in Debian... Would removing/replacing `Nemo` break anything?

Comment: Gnome's file manager is called `nautilus`. Replacing or removing nemo should be absolutely fine

Comment: Sry, I mixed up the GUI and file manager. Yes, in Debian it's `nautilus` (a different fish). What GUI does LMDE4 use and do you suggest to replace it by `gnome`?

Comment: LMDE4 is using cinnamon. There is no need to replace it though (unless you want to). You can simply install `nautilus` and (if you want) remove `nemo` (having both of them is fine as well). As for suggestions on Gnome DE, it comes down down to your specific workflow, so try it out and decide for yourself.

Comment: Okay, thx! I'll get `nautilus` then. I think I would have installed Debian to begin with if the installation process wasn't so involved. The documentation is sub-par

Comment: @kofemann: What is meant by the `gnome` indexer and it being per-user?

Comment: @david As Gnome is a user session manager, the tracker created a search index for each user.

Comment: @kofemann: What's a tracker/indexer? And what does it mean that a search index is created for each user, can one user only search his/her own files? What if I'm the sole user/admin?

Comment: @david It will search in the home directory of the current user.

Comment: @kofemann: *Only* the home directory? This would be pretty useless IMHO, like a Windows Explorer search function that only covers `C:\My Documents`... Thx for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found that this works for me:

`grep -ir [search string] | less`

`-i` ignores cases and `-r` searches recursively in all nested folders. `| less` pipes the output to the pager `less`, so I can scroll through the results.

No need to depend on the make of a certain file explorer!